# how to access oracle oem from another machine?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am a freshman to oracle,but I have ever used sql server.I realize that there is a  graphical console called oem,we can use it from web browser.
the oracle is installed in CentOS 6.3,it is oracle 11g r2.
the os in my computer is win7.
I can access oem in the server machine locally,but I can not access it from my computer using ip address.So what configurations should I do?
my error page like this:
[image: error page]
thank you

Comment: What error do you get?  My first guess is that something in your network is preventing your two machines from communicating with each other.  It is also possible that you're specifying an incorrect IP address.

Comment: thank you,I can ping the server,so the two machines can communicate.when I try to access oem in my web browse with 'http://10.108.218.225:1158/em',10.108.218.225 is the ip of the server,I just get the 'can not access to 10.108.218.225:1158'

Comment: What HTTP error code are you getting?  Can you telnet to the server on port 1158?  My wager is that something in the network is blocking port 1158.

Comment: I did not get a error code,please refer to my edit

Comment: You won't get an error code if a firewall is blocking the port. Have you tried telnet, as JustinCave suggested?

Comment: I can not telnet to the server,is it due to the firewall?

Comment: Do you have root access to the CentOS machine? If so, run "service iptables status". This should show you if the default firewall is running. If it is, you can either add an exception for 1158, or disable it temporarily.